# How to Show Data In List View In Android From Server that sends Multidimensional array

Tags: android, mysql, arrays, listview, multidimensional-array

I am writing a Native Android App in which i am using PHP MYSQL to get data from server Using GET Request.
The way that the server sends me the result is as follows:

```
{
"result": true,
"error_message": "",
"response": [
    {
        "total_tasks": 8,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "id": 8,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Mr. Dejan Mandic"
            },
            {
                "id": 7,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Ms. Charente  Douglas-Smith"
            },
            {
                "id": 6,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Mrs. Alison Marshall"
            },
            {
                "id": 5,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Mrs. Muna Crisp"
            },
            {
                "id": 4,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Mr. Victor Crisp"
            },
            {
                "id": 3,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Mrs. Kathy Dunn"
            },
            {
                "id": 2,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Mr. Peter Dunn"
            },
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Hello Christine, call Ms. Vanessa Allen"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

I need to show the data from the array "respones" -> "tasks" (i.e id and name) in my List View in android and eventually when the user clicks in a particular row in ListView the information about that task is shown in another activity using the id. As the server is sending the data in multidimensional array, I am having problem getting the data in my ListView. 
It would be a great help if someone could kindly help me out.
Thank You :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JSONObject responseObject = new JSONObject(responseString);
boolean resultSuccess = responseObject.getBoolean("result");
if(resultSuccess) {
   JSONArray responseArray = responseObject.getJSONArray("response");
   JSONObject firstResponse = responseArray.getJSONObject(0);
   JSONArray tasks = firstResponse.getJSONArray("tasks");
   for(int i = 0; i < tasks.length(); i++){
      JSONObject task = tasks.getJSONObject(i);
      int id = task.getInt("id");
      String name= task.getString("name");
   }
}
```

You just need to navigate through the tree to parse your json although I had some comments on your JSON tree

1. Why do you have the response as an array? It's only one object
   right?
2. The number of tasks is redundant data you already have the tasks and can infer the length from that.

Comment: Yes it totally worked for me..  Just changed responseArray.getJSONObject(i).. :)